# Letter-spacing bug with custom font - Ionic

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, fonts, ios10

I am utilising a custom font in an app that utilises the Ionic framework. I updated my phone to iOS 10 and the spacing between letters when using this custom font grew massively as shown:

[image]

This is how I declare the custom font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'helveticaneue-thin';
  src:url('../fonts/helveticaneue-thin-webfont.eot');
  src:url('../fonts/helveticaneue-thin-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/helveticaneue-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/helveticaneue-thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/helveticaneue-thin-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If I comment the following line:

```
url('../fonts/helveticaneue-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
```

The spacing is fixed.

Could commenting this line for the time-being cause a problem? Alternatively can anyone shed any light on the cause?

Comment: hmm... I am not sure about the cause of this but maybe the the initial letter spacing is not the same for different font formats

Comment: Weird. Have you tried setting a specific letter-spacing (normal/initial)?